# Why is this question on canceling an .ics import in Google Calendar kept closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, moderation

Timelime:

1. I asked [Cancel .ics import in Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117282/18147) a few years ago.
2. It was closed a few months ago (I believed due to lack of research).
3. I flagged it for reopening a few days ago (since it was clarified that lack of research is not a reason to close questions)
4. I was told in the flag rejection message that I had to add some info, a mod commented what info I needed to add
5. I added some info and the comments got removed (the mod comment + my response)
6. but now the question is still closed.

What shall I do to have the question reopen?

Since the question received 2 downvotes since I flagged it, the question is now at risk of getting automatically removed, so I'm posting the meta question in hope I can get some clarify on what I shall do to have the question reopen before it gets automatically removed.

Comment: So, you flagged it, the flag got rejected telling you to edit it, and you edited it? Have you flagged it again stating you applied the edit? This doesn't really seem to require a Meta post...

Comment: @Cerbrus No: after a mod commented what info I needed to add, I added some info to the question, and the comments got removed (the mod comment + my response). Since my comment got removed, it means one mod saw that I incorporated the feedback, so I though reflagging would be unnecessary. I've just flagged the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After flagging the question as suggested by Cerbrus, a moderator reviewed the flag a reopened the question after making another edit.

Comment: Maybe a different mod removed the comments. Who knows :D Imo, you can accept this self-answer :D